# forwarding mouse events to obscured panel in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have written a program to magnify a portion of an applet using the glass pane of the applet. To do this,I of course use an affine transform to scale the rendered content of the content pane before painting it on the glass pane. However, since mouse events must be scaled inversely by another transform in order to be at the proper location, I must intercept them at the glass pane and transform the coordinates. After doing this, however, I cannot seem to find a way to forward the events to the content pane as it is covered by the glass pane. Initially I tried the Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) method, however this seemed to ignore any events I would attempt to forward. I've had some success manually retrieving the components and calling the methods of each mouseListener and mouseMotionListener, however, these results are buggy at best. Is there a more standard way of sending events to a component?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(theEvent)`

I did not try this myself I I believe it should work. At least as far as I understand this is the UI testing tools use this method.

BTW, how did not implement magnifier? Using Robot?

Comment: posting an event to the SystemEventQueue does not work, it gets me stuck in an infinite loop since I'm trapping input events in the glass pane in order to de-scale the position. I need to post events to the content pane which is beneath the glass pane.

Comment: As for how i implemented the magnifying, I basically just created a BufferedImage the exact size of the applet, then call createGraphics() on the buffered image to get a Graphics2D object which I then apply a scaling AffineTransform object to. next , override the paint method of the GlassPanel, and have it simply draw the buffered image onto the panel. then all thats left is to have a thread which calls paint on the content pane of the applet, and passes in the scaled graphics object of the buffered image.

Comment: I tried reassigning the source object of the event to the component i want to operate on, and this seems to resolve the infinite loop issue, however it still isn't forwarding the events properly.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for description and I am really sorry that my advice did not work for you. See the following link: http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools It contains a list of java testing tools including UI tools. Try to review Jacareto. I am not sure but I think this tool made me thinking that the way I suggested you is correct.